# Seeking to a part of video that hasn't been loaded yet (on progressive download)

Tags: flash, video, progressive-download

I was told there is a server technology that allows user to seek to a part of video that has not been loaded yet even if I am using progressive download, not true streaming.

What technology is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle what you describe, for example: http://h264.code-shop.com/trac#Timeshiftingseek or http://stream.xmoov.com/.

Obviously this won't be able to play data you didn't receive. It's a standard progressive HTTP download where the video file is "cut" on demand server sided.

Comment: what is the name of this technology? how would you call it? ... aha, I see now: "Timeshifting seek - Enable your viewers to immediately jump to any part of the video regardless of the length of the video or whether it has all been downloaded yet."

Comment: Sorry I have un-accepted your answer, I need more info on this.

Comment: I provided you with a link to an open source project where you can see how it works in detail on client side as well as backend, so can't really imagine what kind of "more info" you are looking for. If you could point out where your problems understanding the process lie I might be able to add some informations.

Comment: Then it's me failing to see it there. I will have closer look and reconsider. My problem understanding this technology is that I can not read the code and can't see any overall explanation.

Comment: In a nutshell: When you seek to a time in your video that wasn't loaded yet it sends a standard HTTP request containing the new playhead time. Example: http://someserver.com/videos/testvideo.mp4?starttime=30.4 The server then generates a video stream (basically a new smaller videofile) that starts at the passed timemark. This stream needs to be valid which means that it needs to start with a keyframe and have correct headers/meta data.